# How do I use only service account connections, and not individual connections, in my Forms/SharePoint Flow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, service-account, connection, microsoft-forms

I created a flow with my individual user. For each action within the flow, I chose to use the connection related to a service account (automation_noreply). When I look at the connections listed in the flow details screen, though, it shows connections for me individual account and the service account. When I click on Edit Connections to go to the Flow Owners & Connections in Use screen, it only shows connections related to my individual account, even though they aren't being used in the flow.

The only connections I've chosen are for the service account, and those are the only ones that should be used. I don't understand why my individual connections are still showing up in relation to this flow. Any ideas about what I need to change to ensure that only service account connections are being used?

**Here are the connection details within the flow** - they all show available connections from my individual account and the service account, but for every action I've selected the service account connection (I haven't added screenshots for every actions here, but they are all using the service account connection):

[image]

and:

[image]

**In the connections pane in the flow details screen**, though, it shows both the service account connections that are in use and my individual connections which aren't in use:

[image]

To make it even more confusing, if I click Edit in the connections pane to go to the **Flow Owners & Connections in Use page**, under Connections in Use it only shows my individual connections (even though none of them are used by the flow) and doesn't show any of the service account connections (which are used by the flow):

[image]

So, in summary:

1. I have correctly chosen the connection I want to use for each action in my flow (the service account connection)
2. The Connections section in my flow details page shows a mix of connections actually used in the flow and connections not used in the flow
3. The Flow Owners & Connections in Use page shows only connections which aren't used in the flow (individual) and doesn't show any connections that are in use in the flow (service account)

How do I make sense of this and ensure that my individual connection is never used for this flow?

Comment: Using which account have you created the Flow? Is it your account or the service account? I would suggest exporting the flow, then log in to Power Automate as the *Service Account* and import the flow. While importing, change all connections to the Service Account.

Comment: I did create the Flow with my individual account. I had someone enter the credentials when creating the connections for the service account, but I don't have access to the credentials usually, so I'm not sure if it's possible for me to log in under that account. If so, would the approach be to:
1. Export my flow
2. Import it with the service account, and use service account connections
3. Still as the service account user, add my individual user as an owner to the flow so that I can monitor/update it

Comment: Connections added by the *Creator* of the flow could remain in the flow after it has been shared with others as *Owners*.  But when it is imported by logging in as a *Service account*, you could change all connections. Then the service account can share it with your account so that you could monitor it. It will access all resources using the Service Account.